# Is function surjective?

Tags: functions

For a function $f: R \to R$
$f(x)=x^3$. How is it a onto function.
3 can be codomain of this function. If that is the case, then $x$ must be $\sqrt[3]{3}$.
$\sqrt[3]{3}$ is not a rational number.
Maybe my understanding regarding to this concept is not correct. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is the real numbers, not the rational numbers.  You are correct that this is not onto as a function from rational numbers to rational numbers.  But it is onto as a function from real numbers to real numbers.

Comment: Usually $R$ (or better $\Bbb R$) means *reals* and $\Bbb Q$ means *rationals*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^{3}$ you mean that $f$ has both real inputs and outputs, so there is no reason that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ can't be in the domain.  If you modified the function definition to be $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q},$ for example, then you would be correct that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is not in the domain.